# Programmatically search for a CodedUI Element Without UIMAP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am writing a Windows 8 app in C# and have declared a few Xaml controls (some in my Xaml file and some programmatically). One such control is of type Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid, several controls are of type Windows.UI.Controls.Image, and several are of type Windows.UI.Controls.Canvas.

[This apge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.windowsruntimecontrols.xamlcontrol.aspx#inheritanceContinued) provides a hierarchy of types that ave special cases of XamlControl types, however, there does not seem to be specialized types for Grid or Canvas or Image.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007382/coded-ui-testing-without-uimap) illustrates how to search for specific types of controls based on given search properties.  However, I am not sure how to search for controls of the types noted above.

Any assistance in this regard would be greatly appreciated.