# coded ui without Uimap

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm new to codedUI. I need to know how to write descriptive code in CodedUI.

[Coded UI Testing Without UIMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007382/coded-ui-testing-without-uimap)

In the above link, I tried the code but I met with some errors, which are :

The type or namespace name 'WinWindow' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)

I get the above error for all the windows controls such as winWindow, winButton & winText. Also, another error I get is:

Another error is :

'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ApplicationUnderTest' does not contain a definition for 'SearchFor' and no extension method 'SearchFor' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ApplicationUnderTest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also, in the above mentioned link, what is meant by 'CodedUIExtension File
'. Where to use that code in my project?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards, Mano

Comment: Let Coded UI teach you. Create a sandbox project, use Coded UI to record and generate a test that does have a UI Map. Copy the bits you want from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Adrian.
I'm currently using codedUI for Automation.

Comment: I agree with Adrian, I think a lot of people are too quick to write off the UI map you can actually find synergy with it. I use a combination of UI map to identify the controls and create the control lookup chain. Then I wrap what it finds around my custom control wrappers and create meaningful methods in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same methods that the user on the other question is (using the SearchFor() method), then it would appear that you mean to be using a different framework.  In Coded UI, you specify SearchProperties of the controls.  For example:

```
public HtmlInput MyInputField()
{
    HtmlInput target = new HtmlInput([parent object]);
    target.SearchProperties["id"] = "1";
    // or
    target.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlInput.PropertyNames.Id, "1");
    return target;
}
```

The SearchProperties are a Key/Value pair that are specific to the control type you're using.  Also, you must ensure that the application you're testing against is specified as the parent application (what the other user does when assigning `calWindow = app.SearchFor<blah>([some parameters])`.

If you truly want to create the tests without using a UIMap class (which means you can't just record), I would still suggest using the Page Object model to organize your test architecture.  Martin Fowler wrote a great article describing it here.  Basically, separate your solution into test classes, and then page object classes that contain the definitions to the objects you'll be interacting with.  That way, when you need to change the search properties of a control, you only need to do it once rather than in every test that references it.